# change unicode to accent in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have csv file with a column with unicode inside string while the other column get correctly read with UTF-8
Here the first row:

> Col1 |  Col2
>   rénovation thermique |  ["consommation \u00e9nerg\u00e9tique de b\u00e2timents publics"]

How can I fix the 2nd column so the unicode get transformed to accent ?

Edit: I'm reading the csv with:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',', header=0 )
```

Adding "encoding='utf-8'" doesn't change much

I'm saving the csv with

```
df.to_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

and printing it with either

```
print(df[0:2]) or directly df
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the CSV file? What code do you use to read it? How do you print the result so you see ` \u00e9nerg\u00e9tique`?

Comment: @LutzHorn see my edit, the csv is encoded as UTF-8

Comment: I CAN see the ` \u00e9nerg\u00e9tique` directly by opening the csv file with any text reader

Comment: You're saying your CSV file literally contains the characters "\u00e9nerg\u00e9tique"? Is that fixable at the source?

Comment: Then maybe you should ask the person who generates this CSV to fix the output.

Comment: Yes I can see them in the file, sorry if I wasn't clear and I want to fix/replace those unicode now with python. I can't get another csv

Comment: If your *input* CSV already contains the escape sequences, and also the brackets and quotes, then you need to recover somehow. If all cases are as simple as what you show, you might get away with the ["unicode_escape" codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) and some regexes to strip the brackets and quotes, but for more complex cases you're going to have to use `eval()` (which is risky for untrusted input).

Comment: Another guess: it's possible that this is JSON. Check this: `json.loads('["consommation \u00e9nerg\u00e9tique"]')` returns `['consommation énergétique']` (a Python list with a single Unicode string).

Comment: @lenz look like it's son, thanks, I still have trouble replacing the string of every row with the same srtring applied with json.loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Col2 looks like a single JSON formatted list.  Not sure if this is what you need, but the following will re-write the shown input.csv as the output.csv.  The code assumes the input.csv is encoding in UTF-8.

**input.csv**

```
Col1|Col2
rénovation thermique|["consommation \u00e9nerg\u00e9tique de b\u00e2timents publics"]
```

**rewrite.py**

```
import csv
import json

with open('input.csv','r',newline='',encoding='utf8') as inf, \
     open('output.csv','w',newline='',encoding='utf8') as outf:

    r = csv.reader(inf,delimiter='|')
    w = csv.writer(outf,delimiter='|')

    header = next(r)
    w.writerow(header)

    for col1,col2 in r:
        newcol = json.loads(col2)    # Converts JSON to a list
        w.writerow([col1,newcol[0]]) # Replaces col2 with the list element.
```

**output.csv**

```
Col1|Col2
rénovation thermique|consommation énergétique de bâtiments publics
```

Answer (score 0):

`\u00e9` *is* [é (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm). The file is read and handled correctly by Python.

This character is represented by `\u00e9` on your console when you use `print` on it. If your console would be able to print `é`, you would see what you expect.

On my system, this code

```
s = "é"
print(s)
print(type(s))
print(len(s))

t = "\u00e9"
print(t)
print(type(t))
print(len(t))
```

prints

```
é
<class 'str'>
1
é
<class 'str'>
1
```

which is exactly what I expect.

Comment: I get the same output from the code (I'm using a French windows so its should not be a problem to read accent) but it still print the unicode char in my data frame